# .NET Core EF 2.1 Scaffolding - DatabaseFirst - How to add more tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a clean project solution (intended to be a .NET Core MVC app)

I have two projects - Home.CorePoC.EntityModel and Home.CorePoC.Model
I am calling dotnet cli from Home.CorePoC.Model.

The idea is that I want partial classes and logical separation from custom attributes and attributes from database.

I want to write a PowerShell script that I will be calling when I want to add/remove some tables, columns in tables etc.

In dotnet CLI when I add initially tables, it works just fine:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=sqlServ2016;Database=TestDb;Persist Security 
Info=False;User ID=admin;Password=admin;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
-Tables "Table1","Table2","Table3" -ContextDir "..\Home.CorePoC.EntityModel" 
-OutputDir "TestDB" -force -DataAnnotations -UseDatabaseNames
```

Now, when I want to add just more tables it work as well but I have an error message: "Cannot add 'Table4'. There is already a linked file in this folder with the same name."
Also, I get error in cli console:

> Exception calling "AddFromFile" with "1" argument(s): "A drag operation is already in progress (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040103)"

Must I delete all files and then recreate it (linked file TestContext.cs that was initially created) or there is different way how to avoid this error message which is non-critical (I successfully added Table4 to my models).

I am planning to put this statement into PowerShell script which it will be called from project folder (where I have installed nuget Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools(2.1.4))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because it will try and add the `Context` file for `Table4` but is unable to as one already exists. There is already a [feature request](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/831) to update Entity Framework Core scaffolds rather than having to recreate them every time. You would have to override the generated entities each time by using the `-Force` flag

Comment: I have already included -Force flag. Apparently it works, but I getting the same error..Also, if you know how to delete linked file (Add file as link) through cli console I would be grateful. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I completely missed you'd put the `-Force` flag. When you say you're using `Scaffold-DbContext` I presume you are entering the scaffold using the `Package Manager Console`? If you are creating a Powershell script I would recommend using the dotnet cli command structure `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=SchoolDB;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models` from [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx)

Comment: Also have a look at [this link](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7540#issuecomment-286163842) where someone had the same error as you but whilst completing migrations.